# Javascript method requestFullscreen() hides body elements in the page

Tags: javascript

Currently, the **requestFullscreen()** method in javascript, hides body elements in the page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

```
<body>
   **//click the below button to enable fullscreen**
   <button id="testButton">Set fullScreen</button>

   **// The below button is not visible in the fullscreen page.**
   <button>Testing button</button>

   <div id="testing"></div>
<script>
   // calling the below method will enable fullscreen mode.
document.getElementById("testButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
   document.getElementById("testing").requestFullscreen();
});
</script>
</body>
```

How to overcome this default behavior, of showing the body elements over the fullscreen element(`<div id="testing"></div>`) in the page  ?

Comment: do you have access to edit this page? overcome means what u want to do?

Comment: It works well in my Chromium v92- only `#testing` is visible.

Comment: @Jax-p, @Suresh 

I want the button `<button>Testing button</button>` also to be visible in the fullscreen mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re telling js to make your `div` full screen but it’s empty, try to move your button inside it, it will show. Or instead of selecting only your `div`:

```
document.querySelector("body").requestFullscreen();
```

Comment: Yes, moving it inside the div will work, any way to open the body elements inside fullscreen mode ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, if you want to show all elements you have two options, the first is what I described on the answer itself, you'll select the body with `querySelector('body')` and call `requestFullscreen()` (It's the code on the answer). Another option is to create a `section` or `div` and give an id of `main`, `root` or any name of your choice for that matter, then `document.getElementById('id').requestFullscreen();`.

Comment: Note: I suggest the second approach when manipulating the `DOM`, is best practice not select the whole thing (like querySelector('body')). Also, remember that `requestFullscreen();` is a promise so you can call `then()` on it. best of luck and if you are interested I also would suggest this reading: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions..! #Caio cesar, It helped me :)